inside the useeffect , store update showing indefinite loading in react
i try to update the some data into store. When i try to use props.setReducerData(newData) in code, it is keeps updating the page and page keep loading and shwoing the message
"  Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render"
 useEffect(() => {   
        let DataArray1 = props.DataArray1;  
         
        let DataArray2 = props.DataArray2;  
          
          let newData;
        if(DataArray1  && DataArray1 ?.length > 0 && 
          DataArray2 && DataArray2?.length > 0) 
          {  
              newData = DataArray1 && DataArray1.map(item => {
              const match = DataArray2.some(
                 DataObj => item.id ===  DataObj.id
              );       
              return {
              ...item,
              amount: match ? 0 : 100
              };
            });   
           
             props.setReducerData(newData); // update the new data into store 
         
        } else {
            newData = DataArray1 && DataArray1.map(item => { 
            return {
            ...item,
            amount: 100
            };
          });   
          
         props.setReducerData(newData); // update the new data into store 
         
        }  
       
      },[
        props.DataArray1,
        props.DataArray2
      ]); 


dont update store data in the use effect or dont use use effect for calculation... remove use effect and dont update store after data manipulation... just use in the component...
